# JavaScript Ajax URL 'post' data not received by PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I was wondering if you'd be able to help me with this issue please?

I'm looking to pass variable length HTML (or any data in fact) to a PHP file via POST in a JavaScript AJAX method.

I want to use JavaScript for my entire project so I can cut my teeth on it - I know a lot of solutions are provided in jQuery for AJAX but hopefully you can help me via vanilla JavaScript. :)

I pass the data in the 'prepare' variable in the URL as follows:

```
ajax("doit.php?preparedOutput=" + prepare);
```

The AJAX function:

```
function ajax(queryURL) {
alert(queryURL); // check the right data is being sent
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xhttp.responseText);
        output2.value = xhttp.responseText;
        result.innerHTML = "<h3>your HTML</h3>" + xhttp.responseText;
    }
}
//var encodedQueryURL = encodeURIComponent(queryURL);
xhttp.open("POST", "doit.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//alert(encodedQueryURL); // check the right encoded data is being sent
xhttp.send(queryURL);
}
```

The alerts show me what data is supposedly being sent, whether encoded or not. All seems fine. But the response I get back from the PHP is... nothing.

```
<?php
$preparedOutput = $_POST['preparedOutput'];

echo $preparedOutput;
?>
```

Even if I use isset($preparedOutput) in an if/else block, else is triggered. Nothing's getting through. Not even if I try to pass simple numbers or letters without spaces, aside from HTML. Nothing's getting to the PHP file apparently.

I've been toying with the setRequestHeader, trying all sorts, namely "text/html" etc. Nothing changes the outcome. I feel I'm missing a key piece of the puzzle here!

If it helps, my environment is PHP enabled in IIS7 using FastCGI - if this makes any difference. PHP works, I previously had the PHP script embedded within the same page and it returned the entire page's HTML rather than the HTML in the preparedOutput variable, which is why I shifted it to its own file.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you doubled the url string. Take a look:

You called it by

```
ajax("doit.php?preparedOutput=" + prepare);
```

and the url you use in open is `"doit.php"`

so you basically call something like `http://whatever/doit/?doit.php?preparedOutput=" + prepare`.

Change to:

```
ajax("preparedOutput=" + prepare);
```

Comment: You're magic! I just started watching "back to basics" videos on YouTube as I was at my wit's end. You're a star.

Comment: That's a bit exagerated :D If it was useful to you please accept the answer, thanks. :)

Comment: Just genuinely happy :)